# Opening specific tactic material source

Tags: opening, tactics, training, kings-indian

My chess course kiddies requested KID specific tactics material. Now I never play KID. For Sicilian, I would say "specific" means, for example, Nxb5,Nxe6,Nd5,Nf5...had my fair share of these suicidal knights myself. For KID, immediately the Qxg2+, Nh4+, Ng5/g2# classic came to my mind. It's a bit subjective what is "specific", merely the position resulting from a KID (I mean the main variant with Black going for mate or bust) is not enough (after all White could blunder away material like in any opening).

Thus: Do you know an online source (surely my lib *does* have some opening specific tactic books!) collecting tactics specific (read: illustrative for the ideas of the opening) to a single opening (not necessary KID)? For example, I could imagine there are LiChess collections (but I rarely use LiChess).

Comment: I wish there was an internal "email" function would send you a pgn database i have with a lot of K.I.D surveys and tactics , basically covers ECO E60 through E99 and probably 60 to 70 lines?

Comment: Also there is a forum KingQueenOfChess reasonably ok material however there is ALOT of sifting through the crud to get the gold. Not easily searchable.

Comment: Reddman Got it feel free to delete your comment I'll sift through the 4gb of pgns and books and send what i can

Comment: Email Link sent to a google drive. hopefully you can get something

Comment: @DavidBateman: Could you retry (or directly post the link) since nothing appeared in my mailbox yet? THX.

Comment: @DavidBateman: Whoa, Loooongcat is loooong. THX!

Comment: No worries mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Lichess.org**](https://lichess.org) now includes this feature at https://lichess.org/training/openings.

You can select puzzles that arise out of specific opening lines (as depicted below).

Need to brush up on tactics in the [Jerome Gambit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome_Gambit)?  Lichess has 113 puzzles just for this.

[image: Screenshot of Lichess Puzzles by Openings page showing puzzles for the King's Indian Defense.]
[image: Screenshot of Lichess Puzzles by Openings page showing puzzles for the Italian Game.]

**Selected Openings (# puzzles):**    (see [full list here](https://lichess.org/training/openings))

- Sicilian Defense (118,767)
- Italian Game (40,961)
- Caro-Kann Defense (34,542)
- Scandinavian Defense (28,058)
- Ruy Lopez (24,098)
- Scotch Game (19,661)
- King's Indian Defense (7,614)
- The Orangutan (2,447)

**Choose your side:** Once you select an opening (or specific variation), then you have the option of seeing puzzles for Black only, both sides, or for White only (see below).

[image: Image showing three Kings in a horizontal row. The left King is black indicating this selection leads to puzzles for Black only. The middle King is split half white, half black, leading to puzzles for both sides. The right King is white indicating this selection leads to puzzles for White only.]

Comment: Cool feature, this should be publically known (do we have the "Community Wiki" button?).

Comment: After running an experiment on my favorite Nimzo: "Characteristic" is a debatable feature - from 20 tactics, only one was of the "Oh yes, so I usually get clobbered" type. (Which proves nothing, as my repertoire is nonexistent and I always play the same nonsense :-)

Answer (score 1):

Chessables has a lot of Kings Indian Defence material and much of it is free. Would strongly suggest having a look there first. Also have a look at the modern defence as its quite similar conceptually (I quite like the modern defence and have quite some success with it).

A Chessable Course I would recommend thats free *[Short & Sweet: The King's Indian - FM K. Plinchta](https://www.chessable.com/short-sweet-the-kings-indian/course/31739/)*

In addition to that if you are super keen and happy to spend the money...chessbase has some (by some its actually an obscene amount) Kings Indian Defence lessons. That said I don't think they are really worth the money.

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching for short KID games in the online databases. It's where you might find the "seed games" for some common tactics, as a place to start.